# C++ How do i check for delimiter in this text file

Tags: c++

i am new to C++. I would like to know how do i create a function to check for delimiter.

such as the case below

```
AD,Andorra,AN,AD,AND,20.00,Andorra la Vella,Europe,Euro,EUR,67627.00
AE,United Arab Emirates,AE,AE,ARE,784.00,Abu Dhabi,Middle East,UAE Dirham,AED,2407460.00
AF,Afghanistan,AF,AF,AFG,4.00,Kabul,Asia,Afghani,AFA,26813057.00
```

If the delimiter become $ or # instead of comma , how do i create a function to check for it and say , wrong format of text file.

Thanks!

Below is my readData code

```
void readData ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    NoOfRecordsRead = 0;
    char buffer [Line_Char_Buffer_Size];

    pFile = fopen (INPUT_FILE_NAME , "r");

    if (pFile == NULL) 
        perror ("Error opening file 'Countries.txt' !");
    else
    {
        while ( !feof (pFile) )
        {
            char* aLine = get_line (buffer, Line_Char_Buffer_Size, pFile);

            if (aLine != NULL)
            {
//              printf ("%d] aLine => %s\n", NoOfRecordsRead, aLine);
                globalCountryDataArray [NoOfRecordsRead++] = createCountryRecord (aLine);
            }
        }

     fclose (pFile);

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code that works for comma.

Comment: Post your present working code snippet, so that we can help you better.

Comment: `If the delimiter become $ or # instead of comma , how do i create a function to check for it and say , wrong format of text file` - this **necessarily assumes** that neither $ nor # are **ever** part of data, otherwise there's no way for you to tell whether the use of $ or # was intentional or not

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `FILE * pFile;` is C. So is `printf` and so on!

Comment: I guess get_line() is the function that does the delimiter checking and its a User Defined Function!

Comment: @user1578897-Did you get what were looking for? I have a meta question out and would appreciate some feedback as to the results you received through SO. I was questioning posts like these which ask for C++ advice and present only C code without additional information. Was it the case you were trying to turn C into C++. Your post doesn't show header files, only this one function. So, this could be a dual language(C/C++) program. Curious because all the answers were strictly C++, with only one where the difference was pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

bool detect_comma(std::string file_name)
{
    // open C++ stream to file
    std::ifstream file(file_name.c_str());
    // file not opened, return false
    if(!file.is_open()) return false;
    // read a line from the file       
    std::string wtf;
    std::istream &in= std::getline(file, wtf);
    // unable to read the line, return false
    if(!in) return false;
    // try to find a comma, return true if comma is found within the string
    return std::find(wtf.begin(), wtf.end(), ',')!= wtf.end();
}


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
     if(!detect_comma("yourfile.dat"))
     {
         std::cerr<< "File is not comma delimited!\n";
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }
     // file is OK, open it and start reading
}
```

Edit: Added comments & example code

Comment: Some explanation of what this code does and how it works would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a reliable way to find a location that you always expect the delimiter to be. If the first field is always 2 characters wide, you can check to see if the 3<sup>rd</sup> character is a `,`. Otherwise, you can scan backwards on the first line of text to see if the first non-currency related character is a `,`.

**Edit:** Your `readData` routine is very C-centric, as has been pointed out in comments. You can simplify it considerably by using C++ features.

```
std::string aLine;
std::ifstream pfile(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
while (pfile) {
    std::getline(pfile, aLine);
    if (aLine.size()) {
        globalCountryDataArray.push_back(createCountryRecord(aLine));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to perform your check is using the Boost.Regex library. You only have to define your regular expression and perform a check if your input matches the expression.

Sample code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const string input("AD,Andorra,AN,AD,AND,20.00,Andorra la Vella,Europe,Euro,EUR,67627.00");
  const boost::regex ex("(?:(?!,)(\\d+\\.\\d*)|(\\w|\\s)*)(,(?:(?!,)(\\d+\\.\\d*)|(\\w|\\s)*))*");
  cout << boost::regex_match(input.c_str(), ex) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

By the way: I'm not a regex expert so validate the expression :-)